# Java EE DAO without EJB

Tags: jpa, ejb, ejb-3.1

Is it possible to create a DAO in Java EE environment, which uses JPA, but does not need to be a Stateless bean? I am asking because I have a huge number of EJBs, just because I need a few @Resources in the DAOs, i.e. `EntityManager` and so on.

What would you recommend as a way to simplify DAOs in huge project, it seems to me that having a full EJB (instead of a simple object) for a DAO is eccessive.

DAOs are accessed both from other EJBs and from servlets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible, but not recommended, to inject an `EntityManager` into other types of beans (like e.g. CDI managed beans) along with a `UserTransaction` and then manually manage your transactions.

In Java EE 7, JTA 1.2 contributes CDI compatible extensions for declarative transactions just like EJBs have, but at the moment there's no final release of any Java EE 7 AS yet.

> it seems to me that having a full EJB (instead of a simple object) for a DAO is excessive.

Why do you think that? A "full" EJB is probably more lightweight than any other alternative, and almost certainly more lightweight than any home cooked thing you can come up with based on an `EntityManager`.

Don't forget that EJB beans share their resources automatically and that injection points only get proxies. If you mainly use stateless EJB beans, those proxies are akin to URLs, and not the "real" beans. This makes stateless and local EJB beans incredibly lightweight to inject.

Meaning, if you have a given Service where you inject (say) 10 DAOs, that each have an injected `EntityManager`, and during a given call 3 DAOs are invoked then only 3 beans are actually used and only 1 `EntityManager` instance. It really is rather efficient.

Comment: Why is it "not recommended" to use CDI? Because of transactions (auto managed by EJB) - if I use DAO which is just an object from another EJB, shouldn't it still have transactions (started by EJB)? From my experience, especially with Glassfish, the more EJBs you have, the less stable appserver is.

Comment: @bozo If you always start the call at an EJB the EM in the CDI bean should indeed join the transaction, but your code will be highly dependent on who calls it and you'll have no control over explicitly starting a new transaction (e.g. REQUIRES_NEW).

Comment: @bozo >`From my experience, especially with Glassfish, the more EJBs you have, the less stable appserver is` - So this seems to be the "motivation" behind your question, right? Why do you think this? I mainly use JBoss for large projects, and with hundreds of EJB beans in some I've never encountered any instability that could be attributed to having many EJB beans. I've also never heard of this in any literature, not have I ever encountered anyone else on SO mentioning this.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement DAO as POJO is you want. But the DAO needs an `EntitManager` which must come from somewhere. Either

1. you look it up in the POJO with `InitialContext#lookup`
2. you pass it in the constructor of the POJO

You must pay attention that `InitialContext#lookup` will work only if the parent EJB has declared a dependency to the entity manager, even if it doesn't use it.

Whether it's worth the trouble is a judgment call. Local EJB are very cheap, and having many EJB is not a problem for the app server. It's more a problem of understandability by developpers. (See [this other answer of me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1927421/217862))

Another question to ask is [whether you really need the DAOs](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/jpa_ejb3_killed_the_dao). With EJB 3, they become very thin layer of logic, and it's worth pondering the pros and cons